# In Teradata, SQL Code to count the number of Emergency Visits within 30 days of leaving a hospital

Tags: count, teradata

I have been asked to summarize the counts, by patients, of how many times they visited the emergency room within 30 days of leaving the hospital. I can do a basic SQL query and export to Excel and toss to pivot after doing some manual calculations, but I was wondering if can be all written in SQL?

The basic query is such:

SELECT Patient_ID, Record#, Site, Admit_Date, Discharge_Date
FROM Admissions
WHERE Admit_Date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'

I would like to be able to SUM only on rows where [Site] = 'Hospital' of only visits to the ER within 30 days of leaving the hospital within the query to generate two additional columns:

- AS "Days Since Hospital Discharge"
- AS "ER Visits Within 30 Days After Hospital Discharge and Until Next Hospital Admit"

The output could look like this:

[Sample Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrUhh.png)

I have Googled and search quite a bit and I cannot find answers where I can combine several solutions. I think I may have to do at least two subqueries, but not sure where to embed it. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nested OLAP-functions, this should return the expected result:

```
SELECT dt.*
  ,CASE
     WHEN site = 'Hospital'
     THEN Count(CASE WHEN site = 'ER' AND "Days Since Hospital Discharge"  <= 30 THEN 1 END)
          Over (PARTITION BY Patient_ID 
                ORDER BY Discharge_Date, Admit_Date
                RESET WHEN site = 'Hospital')
   END AS "ER Visits Within 30 Days After Hospital Discharge and Until Next Hospital Admit"

FROM
 ( 
   SELECT Patient_ID, Record#, Site, Admit_Date, Discharge_Date
     ,CASE
        WHEN site <> 'Hospital'
        THEN Admit_Date -
             -- the previous discharge date
             Max(CASE WHEN site = 'Hospital' THEN Discharge_Date END)
             Over (PARTITION BY Patient_ID 
                   ORDER BY Discharge_Date, Admit_Date
                   ROWS Unbounded Preceding)
      END AS "Days Since Hospital Discharge" 
   FROM Admissions 
   WHERE Admit_Date BETWEEN DATE '2019-01-01' AND DATE '2019-12-31'
 ) AS dt
```

Btw, it's easier to help if the data is provided as Create Table + Inserts instead of a jpeg

Comment: You are amazing! That code worked flawlessly! Thank you so much! A few things you had in your code, I completely overlooked such as the "RESET WHEN" which makes perfect sense. I apologize for the not submitting the display data in a table with inserts. I am trying to learn how post the questions to look exactly as how it looks in my SQL editor. 

Again, thank you! If you're ever in the Tampa area - let me buy you lunch and a beer!